# Merge dataframes by left join SQL & Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, merge

I made two tables into a MySQL database using Python. The following SQL code is to perform join on two tables in the database. How can I do the same by writing equivalent python code?

MySQL code:

```
SELECT A.num, B.co_name, A.rep_name
FROM A 
JOIN B 
ON A.num=B.no
```

Desired Python codes:

```
sql = "XXX"    
df_merged = pd.read_sql(sql, con=cnx)
```

Comment: so basically you want to perform join on two tables and store them into pandas dataframe?

Comment: Join the tables and store the merged table on MySQL database, using python code

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912373/importing-multiple-sql-tables-using-pandas) helps you to import multiple tables , post which you can execute the query and store to df.to_sql

Comment: My desired python code for SQL join is similar to discussion found here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020683/which-one-is-effecient-join-queries-using-sql-or-merge-queries-using-pandas]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve by enclosing my query with appropriate apostrophes:

```
sql = '''SELECT A.num, B.co_name, A.rep_name 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.num=B.no ''' 
df_merged = pd.read_sql(sql, con=cnx)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you can take is taking each element one by one and inserting into a new table/data frame.

```
zip( *map(lambda x: pd.read_sql_query(SQL.format(x),connection).loc[0],  
                                      df.yourDataFrame))
```

This is will generate a key value pair, the SQL table as the key and the pandas df as the value. You can them add these values whatever you like (df, or sql table.)

Hoped this helped :)